# How to pull a name attr from an href?

Tags: jquery

Still new at this ... Sorry!  I have a template for multiple pages that functions differently on each one.  As in, the layout looks the same, but the page might be for design, upload, pricing, or getting a template.

On the left is a button for if they know their product dimensions.  Clicking the button takes them to the appropriate page based on their need (i.e. upload page if they clicked the upload button).  The button is dynamic with the template like so:

```
<a id="sg-start-button" class="button blue" href="javascript:void(0);" name="<?php echo $guide_action; ?>">Start Designing!</a>
```

And the script is supposed to pull the value from the "name" attribute and act accordingly.

I'm just not sure how to specify to jquery to look at that value.  Here's what I have:

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() {
    var $guide_action = $('#sg-start-button').I NEED THIS();
    if($guide_action == 'design') start_action(0);
    if($guide_action == 'upload') start_action(1);
    if($guide_action == 'template') start_action(2);
    if($guide_action == 'price') start_action(3);
});
```

I tried the attr tag (.attr('name')) but that wasn't it.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: you dont't start js variables with $.

Comment: @gopi1410 it is not any problem to start a variable name with `$`

Comment: `var $guide_action = this.name;` should work fine.

Comment: yeah, it works but I thought he may be confused with js & php variables, so just thought mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I think you want something like this:

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $guide_action = $(this).attr('name');
    if($guide_action == 'design') start_action(0);
    if($guide_action == 'upload') start_action(1);
    if($guide_action == 'template') start_action(2);
    if($guide_action == 'price') start_action(3);
});
```

Comment: I tried this .. But for some reason I get the error "$("#sg-start-button").attr("name") is not a function"   I tried adding the e.preventDefault, etc that you have in your example, but the same error keeps popping up.

Comment: Oh, I figured out my mistake.  I was typing .attr('name')(); ... those extra ()'s were getting me.  Haha, thank you for your help!  You guys all had the proper answer, I just didn't type it right.  Thank you again!! I will learn this eventually. :)

Comment: I would definitely use a `switch` there... no need to continue the other `if`'s after return from that `start_action()` method...

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() 
{
    console.log($(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr("name")` works.
Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/Z7gG9/)

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() {
  var guide_action = $('#sg-start-button').attr("name");
  alert(guide_action);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use the attr() method.

So your code would look like:

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() {

     var $guide_action = $('#sg-start-button').prop('name');

     switch($guide_action) {

        case 'design':
          start_action(0);
          break;

        case 'upload':
          start_action(1);
          break;

        case 'template':
          start_action(2);
          break;

        case 'price':
          start_action(3);
          break;

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should use `prop()`:

```
$('#sg-start-button').click(function() {
    var guideAction = $(this).prop('name')
});
```

However, IMO it would be more semantic to use `data-x` attributes, like this:

```html
<a id="sg-start-button" class="button blue" href="#" data-guide-action="<?php echo $guide_action; ?>">Start Designing!</a>
```

```javascript
$('#sg-start-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var guideAction = $(this).data("guide-action")
});
```

Comment: I'll save this as a ref, seems a bit over my head for now as a total noob, lol.  But thank you, it should be useful in the future. :)